# Why does adding maps using latest google_maps_flutter fail

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I am failing to add google maps to my flutter app using the latest pub version.

```
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1
```

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/gunnar/git/chess-champion/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m:9:16: error: property 'provideAPIKey' not found on object of type 'GMSServices'
      [GMSServices.provideAPIKey@"MyApiKey"];
                   ^
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: property 'provideAPIKey' not found on object of type 'GMSServices

You need to include your API key in your ios folder as per [google maps plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

```
 ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m

    #include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

in swift `ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:`

```
   import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR KEY HERE")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

from [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_services)

> - (BOOL) provideAPIKey:       (NSString *)    APIKey
>
> Provides your API key to the Google Maps SDK for iOS.
>
> This key is generated for your application via the Google Cloud
>   Platform Console, and is paired with your application's bundle ID to
>   identify it. This must be called exactly once by your application
>   before any iOS Maps SDK object is initialized.
>
> Returns:
>       YES if the APIKey was successfully provided.

Comment: It is already there! (I switched it to "MyApiKey" in the error text since i didn't want to share my key with the world.) So this is not the cause of my problem.

Comment: Its more like my version of GMSServices does not have the property provideAPIKey

Comment: `[GMSServices.provideAPIKey@"MyApiKey"];` this was wrong

Comment: I am now trying with `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MyApiKey"];`

Comment: glad it worked.would appreciate if you did mark as answer

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this error because I was **forgetting to include the GoogleMaps dependency in the AppDelegate.m iOS file**. Make sure to include this within the imported dependencies:

```
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
```

This will be your final product:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"ABCDEFG123456789_v4"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

You can copy and paste this and it will work, simply replace ABCDEFG123456789_v4 with your API key. ~cheers

Answer (score 0):

In my AppDelagte.m file i had entered

```
[GMSServices.provideAPIKey@"MyApiKey"];
```

which turned out to be wrong. It should be

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MyApiKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to add this line in swift ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:

import GoogleMaps